# Getting error NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: in "big.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/div/h3/a")).click();"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

```
package FlipPkg;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BigBasket {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\NP031997\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.12.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver big = new FirefoxDriver();
    big.get("https://www.google.com/");
    big.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("The webpage is:" + big.getTitle());

    big.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']")).sendKeys("Big Basket");
    big.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    big.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/div/h3/a")).click();

    System.out.println("The current webpage is:" + big.getTitle());

    }
}
```

the code is failing at position

```
big.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/div/h3/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine.The WebDriver will find that element for sure, but you have a small problem in that code. There might be two reasons for NoSuchElementException:

1. The WebDriver won't take any delay for finding the link that you are finding with your code. The WebDriver will not wait for the search results page to load, so you will get NoSuchElementException.
2. The link's xpath may vary dynamically because google will retrieve dynamic search results.

The solutions for this are as follows:

You have to use waits after the 'enter' functionality.

1. You can use waits or waitForPageToLoad() function. The following code is for WebDriverWait.

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(big,120);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/div/h3/a"));
   ```
2. You can use this for clicking the element by

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(big, 15);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Big Basket")));
   ```
3. You can also use Contains() function for finding the XPath of the element:

   ```
   //a[contains(text(),’Big Basket’)]
   ```

By using 2nd and 3rd method you will get a list of elements because many elements contains the Text Big Basket.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The issue got resolved.  I used the code: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(big, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Big Basket"))).click();

Comment: As you are saying your issue got resolved. Then please mark the answer as correct so that others wouldn't waste their time to check the question again and try to give the answer.